# how to get NF from AWK argument?

Tags: unix, awk, argv

I've been trying to get the NF from 2 arguments (not files) in awk without success .

This is the command line:

```
awk -f the_program 12/12/2013 11/11/2014
```

Is it possible to some how pipe ARGV[1] or ARGV[2] to getline to get NF?
I wanted to get NF so I can easily validate the arguments before doing other stuff with them

Comment: Some example would be great.  What do you need? NF=Number of Fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in pure awk:

```
$ awk -F/ 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++) {print split(ARGV[i], a) }}' 12/12/2013 11/11/2014
3
3
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it can be done alone using `awk`. Try using wrapper `bash` script around it.

**myscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN {
  RS=" "; FS="/";
} 
{
  print NF;
}' <(echo $*)
```

Test

```
% myscript.sh 12/12/2013 11/11/2014
3
3
```

---

Or eliminating use of `echo` with `<<<` as suggested by *@fedorqui*

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN {RS=" ";FS="/";} {print NF}' <<<$*
```

Comment: Well done! Another possibility would be doing `awk 'BEGIN{RS=" "; FS="/"} {print NF}' <<< "12/12/2013 11/11/2014"`

Answer (score 0):

Is this all you want?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ print ARGC - 1 }' 12/12/2013 11/11/2014
2
```

If not, post some expected output and explain why.